# c/c++ windows remote debugger DebugActiveProcess error 50 ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: c++, c, windows, debugging

Hi I'm trying to build an external debugger in c/c++ in windows. So far My goal for now is just to attach my debugger to a processs and then catch some breakpoints. So far I managed to run process from the code using `CreateProcessA` and I succeeded to catch breakpoints. But I want to attach to external process. Here is my code:

```
void attachProcess(DWORD pid) {
    errCheck("before obtaining handle");
    /*
     * if I uncomment those 2 lines I also succeed to obtain the handle but the pid changes(it finds the proper process, tested it)
     *
    HWND wnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Kalkulator");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd, &pid);
     */
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid);
    if(handle == 0) {
        log("no process hanle obtained - process not found", ERR);
        return;
    }
    log("handler obtained", POSITIVE);
    log<void*>(handle, POSITIVE);
    errCheck("after obtaining handle");
    if(DebugActiveProcess(pid)) {
        log("attached to process, pid:",POSITIVE);
        log<DWORD>(pid,POSITIVE);
        DEBUG_EVENT debug_event = {0};
        while(WaitForDebugEvent(&debug_event, INFINITE)) {
            handleDebugEvent(&debug_event);
            ContinueDebugEvent(debug_event.dwProcessId, debug_event.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
        }
    } else {
        log("unable to attach to process, pid:", ERR);
        log<DWORD>(pid,ERR);
        errCheck("attaching");
    }
    CloseHandle(&handle);
}
```

This code succeeds to get the handle but it crashes on `DebugActiveProcess` with error `50` `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`. My Windows is 64 bit so is the calc process(I assumed that because in task manager there isn't a note that it is 32-bit). Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

This is the example output btw:

```
[+] handler obtained
[+] 0xe8
[!] unable to attach to process, pid:
[!] 7212
[!] attaching | error occured 
[!] 50
```

Comment: Does WinDbg attach?

Comment: yes `windbg(X64)` is able to attach to it

Comment: https://github.com/r41p41/snippets/blob/master/debugpriv.c#L32

Comment: @HansPassant that did not work :/ I used `EnableDebugPrivileges` and I still get error 50

Comment: It might be too late, but I had the same issue, and I found out, 32-bit processes can not attach to 64-bit processes. So try run your code with x64 build config.